# How do I retrieve the data from a DataTable store in a DataSet and store it in an array?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I am trying to retrieve the data from a DataTable within a DataSet and store it into an array.

Previously I was just retrieving and storing the data from a DataTable into an array using the following code.

```
var stringArr = DtTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ExampleId")).ToArray();
```

and it worked. So I decided to modify it to access the DataSet like so

```
var stringArr = DtSet.Tables["Results"].TableName.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ExampleId")).ToArray();
```

I now get the following error message and is unsure how to fix

> Error CS1929  'char' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow

Comment: A DataTable (which need not be stored in a DataSet at all) is a perfectly usable container - why move it at all?

Comment: TableName should not be in chain. It returns name of the table as string. Enumerable iterates chars

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I have multiple DataTables that's why I'm using DataSet.

Comment: Curious... why do you want it in an array? Lists are so much easier to work with.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I'm new to c# so I'm just playing around. I'll look into lists. If I decided to use lists how would I go about achieving in the above question tho?

Comment: Yeah, I think you'll find lists way easier to work with. But, another question... in your first example, is `DtTable` the same datatable as `DtSet.Tables["Results"]` from the second example?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Yes it is. `  dataTableResults = dataSet.Tables.Add("Results");` This is how I stored it inside the DataSet

Comment: In your second example, what would happen if you took out `.TableName`?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Does not print anything when I try to output the information

Comment: Are you able to set and hit breakpoints?  I'd be curious to know what this line gives you: `var myTable = DtSet.Tables["Results"];` It SHOULD give you a datatable that is the same as `DtTable`. If it doesn't then something is wrong with `DtSet.Tables["Results"]`.  The answer by Gwinn below should be the right anwer, assuming DtSet.Tables["Results"] is valid.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I'll take a look further into it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you added `TableName` in the chain.

You are basically asking to turn the `TableName` in an `IEnumerable` (which returns an `IEnumerable<char>`) and for every `char` of the table name string your are trying to call `.Field` which of course does not exist.

You need to write:

```cs
//Notice TableName being removed
var stringArr = DtSet.Tables["Results"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ExampleId")).ToArray();
```

Removing `TableName` from the chain will return the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` that you need.

Comment: see the comments under the OP. I suggested this too, but OP said he gets an empty set.

Comment: Yes I now Get an empty String when I try to print out the data. `   foreach (var item in stringArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stringArr);
            }
`

Comment: See my most recent comment. This SHOULD be the right answer. If it's not then `DtSet.Tables["Results"]` is giving you an empty data table.

Comment: I thought the question was about the compiler error, I didn't saw the comments while writing the answer. 
@pennyBoy Are you sure that your table 'Results' contains any data and that column 'ExampleId` actually has any values ?

Comment: I'll ask another question in another post. But, essentially I have two classes. Class A, I create 3 data tables and store them into a data Set that I pass to class B. In class B, I copy the dataSet from A into a new dataSet in B. I then try to retreive the tables, store them in an array and print out the results.